# How to get URL (including parameters) from Retrofit Call object

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a central web-request controller in my app that all requests, made using Retrofit go through it.

Now, I want to add an extra check when a new request comes in, to see if the same request is still on fly, that is no response (success or failure) arrived yet, to be able to drop the second one.

The question is, how can I get the full URL (including parameters) from a Retrofit Call object, so that I can implement this functionality?

P.S. I am using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2

Comment: The only way to know that a request is still active is before onSuccess is called; I am not sure there is a way to tell before that though

Comment: May I know how cna you find it if you get full URL ?